# Reading and making use of XML saved in DB (LOB)

Tags: javascript, node-oracledb

[image]

```
    connection.execute(
      `select SSG_RESP_XML from SSG_SR_RESP_DTLS where SERV_PROV_REQ_ID='141220181657' and SSG_RESP_TYPE='NOTIFICATION'`,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        var lob = result.rows[0][0];
        console.log(lob);
        fs.writeFile('xd.xml',lob, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err) {
          return doRelease(connection);
        });

      });
```

I need to save the xml to a file as well as parse and use it in the further lines in the program.

In xd.xml file `[object Object]` is seen.

```
`console.log(lob)` I receive the following
```

[image]

How to fetch the xml from the object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse xml array values with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057599/parse-xml-array-values-with-node-js)

Comment: @EriksKlotins I need to parse the LOB data from a DB column. No issues about accessing elements in XML. Problem is how i access the XML first of all.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? What if you cast the lob to varchar at database level?

Comment: Oracle DB. I am using oracledb package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explore two ways.

1. Use `fetchAsString` method from [oracledb package 1.12.1](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/node-oracledb-112:-working-with-lobs-as-string-and-buffer-connection-pinging)
2. Cast your LOB to varchar2

   select TO_CHAR(SSG_RESP_XML) from SSG_SR_RESP_DTLS where SERV_PROV_REQ_ID='141220181657' and SSG_RESP_TYPE='NOTIFICATION'

Comment: Which option did you use at the end?

Comment: Option 2 Thanks

Comment: node-oracledb 3.1 will automatically return XMLTYPE columns as varchar, but the length is limited to 4k or 32K, depending on your varchar size.   In general, fetching with `GETCLOBVAL` like `var sql = 'SELECT XMLTYPE.GETCLOBVAL(res) FROM resource_view'` is way to go, see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#xmltype